# Error while testing localdb instance of oracle in SSIS

Tags: oracle, ssis

I am working on an SSIS project where I am supposed to transfer data from the development server of MS SQL Server to the localDB instance of my Oracle system on a regular basis.
I am able to test the development server of SQL Server, but while testing localDB instance in SSIS through OLEDB Destination it fails with the below error:

The test connection failed because of an error in initializing the provider. ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

How to resolve this error ??

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this links already? https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-resolve-ora-28040-no-matching-authentication-protocol/ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/588911/how-to-solve-ora-28040-error-no-matching-authentic

Comment: FriendlyDragon Not able to understand the content of blog on how to do aspect..